How can we make data table as optional in the cucumber?
can we make the data table optional argument, I have two cases in the below for both cases
When(/^I (enter|select)?(( and select)? the following fields )?( "(.*?)" in the )("(.*?)" field )?in the files management page$/, function (actionType, condition, value, fieldName, table) {
    filesManagementUtil.enterOrSelectValueInFilesManagement(actionType, value, fieldName, table);
});

the step should be
When I enter "Field Value" in the "Business Name" field in the files management page

When I enter the following fields in the files management page
            | FieldName     | FieldValue  | Action |
            | Business Name | Field Value | Enter  |

The step definition should work for both cases in the below
When I enter "Field Value" in the "Business Name" field in the files management page

When I enter the following fields in the files management page
            | FieldName     | FieldValue  | Action |
            | Business Name | Field Value | Enter  |


I think you're over complicating it. You don't have to reuse the same step definitions to this extreme. You can extract a helper function to reuse the code.

You can't.  You need to use two steps.  See below:
/**
 * When I enter "Field Value" in the "Business Name" field in the files management page
 */
this.When(/^I enter "(.*)" in the "(.*)" field in the files management page$/, { timeout: IO_WAIT }, function step(value, field) {
    enterFieldValue(value, field);
});



/**
 * When I enter the following fields in the files management page
 */
this.When(/^I enter the following fields in the files management page:$/, { timeout: IO_WAIT }, function step(table) {

    if (table.rawTable[0].length < 1) {
        assert.ok(false, 'Table is misconfigured in scenario.');
    }

    table.rawTable[0].forEach((value,field) => {
        enterFieldValue(value, field);
    }
        
});

